# C# Assistance in foreach datagridview data removal

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, datagridview

Scenario: I am loading a DataGridView with data from a database, so in order to do so I'm using a foreach-loop, now the problem here is that when going on the DataGridView for the second time it loads the data from before and the data being looped in now.

In order to fix that I did this:

```
    private void ViewAvailProd_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numRows = AvailProd_DGV.RowCount;

        foreach (TBL_Product prod in DataLProducts.GetProducts())
        {
            if (numRows > 1)
            {
                AvailProd_DGV.Rows.Clear();
            }

            AvailProd_DGV.Rows.Add(prod.ProductID, prod.Name, prod.Category, prod.Price, prod.Stock, "Purchase");
        }
        this.PNL_ViewAvailProd.Visible = true;
    }
```

However, another problem arisen were it does this:

Before;

[image]

After;[image: c]

If I then type in this code:

```
    private void ViewAvailProd_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AvailProd_DGV.Rows.Clear();

        foreach (TBL_Product prod in DataLProducts.GetProducts())
        {
            AvailProd_DGV.Rows.Add(prod.ProductID, prod.Name, prod.Category, prod.Price, prod.Stock, "Purchase");
        }
        this.PNL_ViewAvailProd.Visible = true;
    }
```

This would be the output:

Before;

[image]

After;[image]

Comment: are you setting the datagridview `datasource` to `datatable` you retrieve from database? if so set `AvailProd_DGV.DataSource=null` before every reload from database

Comment: Yes, however that then displays the results 3 times over

Comment: Can you show us the code for `DataLProducts.GetProducts()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You check your rowcount at the beginning of the method, which results in >1 so every time you execute your if in your loop it will clear all the rows and only add one row. To counter this, just clear all your rows at the beginning of your method and then load them all in again. Like so:

```
private void ViewAvailProd_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AvailProd_DGV.Rows.Clear();

    foreach (TBL_Product prod in DataLProducts.GetProducts())
    {
        AvailProd_DGV.Rows.Add(prod.ProductID, prod.Name, prod.Category, prod.Price, prod.Stock, "Purchase");
    }
    this.PNL_ViewAvailProd.Visible = true;
}
```

**Edit**
**Reconstruction**
If I load up my own testcode for this method it seems to work just fine.

```
public List<Product> GetProducts()
{
    List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
    list.Add(new Product() { Id = 0, Name = "Fnatic", Category = "eSports", Price = 1000000, Stock = 1 });
    list.Add(new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "G2", Category = "eSports", Price = 500000, Stock = 4 });
    list.Add(new Product() { Id = 2, Name = "SKT", Category = "eSports", Price = 2000000, Stock = 0 });
    list.Add(new Product() { Id = 3, Name = "Roccat", Category = "eSports", Price = 150000, Stock = 17 });
    return list;
}

private void ViewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.Rows.Clear();

    foreach (var product in GetProducts())
    {
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(product.Id, product.Name, product.Category, product.Price, product.Stock, "Purchase");
    }
}
```

When using this, every time I click the ViewButton im getting this dataGridView:
[image]

Comment: I did that before, it seemed like the most obvious thing to do, however, it's not working either...

Comment: @user7943 Try to explain how its not working, maybe I can help you out further?

Comment: It doesn't do any removing at all, the data will just multiply itself

Comment: @user7943 I've added my own test code for your case to show that the solution should currently work for the information that is given. Please try it out yourself and look if anything differs from your own solution.

Comment: Hi Huntt, I've updated the question to show you my outcome of that process.

Comment: @user7943 Alright, just to check, `DataLProducts.GetProducts()` really just returns one set of products right? Not two? And have you by any chance set the Data Source on the datatable? If so can you try setting that to none since you are filling the datatable manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162336/discussion-between-user7943-and-huntt).